# DolphinDB: obtain the length of the longest continuous positive subvector？

Tags: database, dolphindb

I have a time-series table containing only one column of data in addition to the date column. I want to evaluate the continuity of the positive data in that column, is there any suggested function? This scenario is more like MACD crossing above zero line that lasts a certain time, and I want to consider the positive continuity.

I'd take a simplified example:
a given vector (-1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1) with multiple consecutive 1 included. The more consecutive positive elements the subvector has, the higher evaluating score returns. Let me know if any function applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxPositiveStreak(X) and it returns the maximum value of the sum of consecutive positive elements of X.
For example, 1, 2, 3, 1 is the longest streak that meets the requirement, so the length 4 will be returned.

```
v =  10 -1 0 0 1 2 3 1 0 0 -1 -1
maxPositiveStreak(iif(v>0, 1, 0))
```